# Button Won't Click Mobile Safari

Tags: html, mobile, button, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

I have a few buttons on my web page that work fine on all browsers that i have tested but mobile safari(Iphone, Ipad, etc)

If you go to: http://www.divisionforty.com/

and click on view video or more info you will see that nothing happens where as another button on the same page further down works fine.

Here is the code:

```
    <div id="hero">
           <div class="page-header pull-left"><h1>you deserve a better web experience!</h1>
            <p>inroducing a complete web presence service that is designed to ease your companies workload while increasing user ease.<br> <a href="services.php"> learn more</a></p>


            <a href="#" id="videofade" class="button">watch video</a>                              


            </div>


    </div>
```

For some reason only these buttons seem to not be working.

Hope someone can help

Denver

Comment: check your CSS. display: block?

Comment: Are you using the `display:` property on your CSS? I bet your button displaying as an inline element or somehow has a zero height.

Comment: would you mind taking a look because i can't seem to find anyplace where it is or why it would only happen in that once spot on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a fix. It was messing up because

```
<video id="videopromo" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:-1;" controls poster="video/video.jpg" width="100%" height="500">
  <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="video/player.swf"
width="854" height="504">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.mp4">
    <!--[if IE]><!--><param name="movie" value="player.swf">
    <!--<![endif]-->


    <img src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/4791/video.jpg" width="100%" height="500" alt="Video">
    <p>Your browser can't play HTML5 video. <a href="video/video.webm">
Download it</a> instead.</p>
  </object>
</video>
```

was placed above

```
<div id="heroslider">

            <div id="hero">
                   <div class="page-header pull-left"><h1>you deserve a better web experience!</h1>
                    <p>inroducing a complete web presence service that is designed to ease your companies workload while increasing user ease.<br> <a href="services.php"> learn more</a></p>


                    <a href="#" id="videofade" class="button">watch video</a>                              


                    </div>


            </div>

    </div>
```

I just hide the video with a display:none which cancels when the button is clicked.

Now everything works as you can test on mobile at http://divisionforty.com

Denver